# I Have a Problem with foreign key constraint

Tags: laravel

**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `project`.`#sql-4b4_46` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `projects` add constraint `projects_owner_id_foreign` foreign key (`owner_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)**

```
 Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->bigIncrements('id');
                    $table->unsignedInteger('owner_id');
                    $table->string('title');
                    $table->text('description');
                    $table->timestamps();
                    $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
                    });
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

Comment: The issue might be due to creation ordering of `projects` and `users` tables. Try creating the `users` table before defining schema create for `projects`. Also, the `projects.owner_id` could be _bigInteger_ type to match the _bigIncrements_ for `users.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `unsignedBigInteger` when using foreign keys

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('owner_id');
```

And, surely, you have to create the target table first  So, create `users` first and after that create `projects`

Answer (score 0):

Create users table first, then create projects table and assign foreign key to users.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key is using `unsignedBigInteger`, the foreign key should also be using `unsignedBigInteger`.

```
     Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
     });

   Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('owner_id');
                $table->string('title');
                $table->text('description');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
   });
```